# C# window application GUI halt on re-sizing

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface

C# windows application's GUI halt on re-sizing application and i have to kill the process from task Manager.
I have search for the issue and got a link that point me to background invoker and other point me to userpreferencechange events. 
I have check the userpreferencechange event and its fired but don't know how to handle this issue in this event.

Comment: Winforms or WPF? and your code please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in one of these four:

- `OnSizeChanged()` method
- `OnResize()` method,
- `SizeChanged` event handler, or
- `ReSize` event handler.

They all get fired whenever your gui get's resized. I suspect that in one of these event handlers/methods you have some code that tries to do something fancy that either results in an exception, recursion or an infinite loop.

But, without you providing more detailed code, this is, of course, merely an educated guess.